# Finding primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and consider the ideal $I=(xz,yz)$ of $K[x,y,z]$.
>   Find a primary decomposition of $I$.

Now I'd say the primary decomposition is $(z)\cap (x,y)$. To see that, we clearly have $(xz,yz)\subseteq (z)\cap (x,y)$ since each of the generators lies in each of the ideals. For the other way, I'm a little uncertain. My approach is negating the expression. So take an element $f$ which is not in $(xz,yz)$. This means that either $f$ consists of terms with $z$, or it consists of terms with $xy$, or it consists of constant terms. In either three cases, $f$ will also not be in $(z)\cap (x,y)$, so $(z)\cap (x,y)\subseteq (xz,yz)$. Is this correct?

Also I need to show that $(z)$ and $(x,y)$ are primary ideals. I do this by showing they are prime. 
$(x,y)$ is prime since $K[x,y,z]/(x,y)\cong K[z]$ is a integral domain, since $K$ is a field.
For $(z)$, take $fg\in (z)$, so $fg=hz$ for some $h\in K[x,y,z]$. Assume $f\notin (z)$, so $f$ have a term, without $z$, but since $fg=hz$, then $g$ must have $z$ in all of it's terms, and so $g\in (z)$. Are this valid?

Comment: The second part is correct (I only wonder why don't consider the quotient $K[x,y,z]/(z)$?), but I'm afraid the first one is not so clear.

Comment: I mean a primary decomposition - my bad. For the first part, is the negating wrong, or should I be more strict with showing that elements that are not in $(xz,yz)$ are not in $(z)\cap (x,y)$?

Comment: I don't really see why $K[x,y,z]/(z)$ would be an integral domain?

Comment: $K[x,y,z]/(z)\simeq K[x,y]$.

Comment: This is how I'd prove the first part (pretending that I know nothing about monomial ideals): if $f\in(z)\cap(x,y)$ then $f=zg$ and since $zg\in(x,y)$ and $z\notin(x,y)$ we get $g\in(x,y)$ (you know that $(x,y)$ is a prime ideal!), so $zg\in(zx,zy)$.

Comment: You can look at Notes of Lectures  http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~jkv/acag/   titled  as $`` $Five lectures on Computational Commutative Algebra by Ravi Rao$"$.